# Run timeupdate once per second

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want my timeupdate function to run once a second. Is this possible? ( VUE CLI )

```
@timeupdate="videoSecond"

videoSecond(){
    let Second = this.player.currentTime();
    let CaptureList = this.capturesList;

    CaptureList.forEach(element => {
      if(element.timeStart == Math.round(Second)){
        console.log(element.id);
        console.log(element.timeStart);
      } else {
        console.log('Olmadı');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method.

In your case you could use it like that :

```
mounted () {
  setInterval(this.videoSecond, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'll be returning soon.